# Search of tags that contain symbols is broken in Careers UK

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Searching for [C#](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/uk/jobs/tag/c%23) or [C++](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/uk/jobs/tag/c%2b%2b) always redirect to C jobs.

Comment: The non-UK versions work just fine: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/c%23 and http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/c%2b%2b

Answer (score 5):

Confirmed. Thanks for reporting this! <s>Fix coming shortly.</s> This issue is now fixed.

Comment: as a side question: how can I access tag search from the frontend?

Comment: also, why do I get non-matching items? http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/d

Comment: @yi_H there's no exact match for "D", i.e. no active job listing has been tagged with just "D" (unlike "C"). So what you see is the next best type of match, tags with the letter "D" in it. Like "proDuct-management". Should anyone post a job listing with the tag "D", it'll show up on top of that list.

Comment: I understand that you describe this as a feture, but FYI, as a user (who is seeking for a job) I see this as a bug. Also, if I visit http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/c, I see objective-c, c# (mixed, not on the bottom of the list!) and other things I'm not even remotely interested in. Again, you can call this "as-designed", but i doubt that's what the users expect/want. Let me know whether it makes sense to open a new question for this.